# ¿Qué posición ocupa y qué función tiene "Los niños" en "Los niños parece que están divirtiéndose mucho"?

Tags: gramática, sintaxis

En español, como en inglés y otras lenguas, hay ciertos verbos que se comportan como *raising predicates*, es decir, permiten, y de hecho obligan a, que el sujeto de la cláusula que debe servirles como complemento «ascienda» desde ella y se convierta en su propio sujeto. Se trata, sobre todo, de los verbos *parecer* y *resultar*, cf. (1) y (2):

- **1a.** Los niños parece**n** [ __ estar divirtiéndose mucho] <sub>(con «ascenso» del sujeto: *gramatical*)</sub>
- **1b.** *Parece**n** [los niños estar divirtiéndose mucho] <sub>(sin «ascenso» del sujeto: *agramatical*)</sub>
- **2a.** Los ligues de Clara siempre resulta**n** [ __ ser casados y con niños] <sub>(con «ascenso»: *correcta*)</sub>
- **2b.** *Resulta**n** [los ligues de Clara ser casados y con niños] <sub>(sin «ascenso»: *agramatical*)</sub>

Al lado de esa construcción, en español, pero ya no en inglés (por el «efecto *that t*»), tenemos otra en la que también participan los verbos *parecer* y *resultar*, pero junto a otros «predicados» (e.g., *ser [que...]*, *poder*, y algunos que ni siquiera son verbos, como *ojalá*, *seguro*, *claro*, *naturalmente*). Se caracteriza por que la cláusula subordinada lleva un *que* y un verbo en forma personal (en indicativo o subjuntivo, según los casos), en vez de un infinitivo. Es una construcción que también permite, pero ya NO exige, que el sujeto de la subordinada «ascienda» hasta delante del verbo *parecer*, como ocurre en **3.** (y ocurriría en ejemplos paralelos con *resultar*, *es*, *ojalá*, *claro*, *seguro*, *naturalmente*, etc., que omito para abreviar).

- **3a.** Los niños parec**e** [que __ est**án** divirtiéndose mucho] <sub>(con «ascenso»: *gramatical*)</sub>
- **3b.** Parec**e** [que los niños est**án** divirtiéndose mucho] <sub>(sin «ascenso»: *gramatical*)</sub>
- **3c.** *Los niños parec**en** [que __ est**án** divirtiéndose mucho] <sub>(con «ascenso» a «sujeto»: *agramatical*)</sub>

Como *parecer*, *resultar*, etc. son básicamente predicados monádicos (*Parece/Resulta [que] X*), los hechos de **1.-3.** no deben sorprendernos. Los ejemplos **1b.** y **2b.** son agramaticales porque esos infinitivos no pueden llevar sujetos pronunciables. En **1a.** y **2a.** ese problema se ha eliminado haciendo que *los niños* se convierta en sujeto de verbos en forma personal, que sí permiten sujetos explícitos, aunque para ello hay que asignar a *parecer/resultar* una inflexión de plural que oculta el hecho de que su verdadero argumento (= LO que parece o resulta) es toda la cláusula de infinitivo, no *los niños*. En **3b.**, por el contrario, no ha sido necesario *manipular* nada: la inflexión de *parec**e*** indica que su sujeto sintáctico coincide con su sujeto nocional, la cláusula subordinada, mientras que la inflexión de plural de *est**án*** muestra que su propio sujeto es *Los niños*, de modo obvio en **3b.** De hecho, **3b.** es la versión «básica» de esa oración (i.e., aquella en la que cada cosa está «en su sitio» y concuerda con lo que le corresponde). Finalmente, digamos que **3c.** es agramatical porque tiene dos verbos no coordinados con el mismo sujeto *los niños* y a la vez contiene un sujeto de *parecer*, la subordinada, que no puede concordar con su predicado. Hay explicaciones más poderosas; **3c.** infringe principios generales de Economía, Teoría del Caso, etc., pero presuponen una teoría lingüística que quizá no es apropiado presuponer aquí.

Es la existencia de **3a.** la que SÍ me resulta sorprendente: *Los niños* aparece «desplazado» a una posición ante *parece*, pero ese «ascenso» es *opcional*, puesto que **3b.**, sin él, es gramatical. Hay que suponer, pues, que **3a.** es una construcción *marcada*, que se emplea cuando “los niños”, aparte de sujeto de “están divirtiéndose”, tiene alguna otra función que no podría desempeñar dentro de la subordinada. Pero ¿*cuál* es esa “otra” función? La pregunta va inevitablemente ligada a otra: ¿*cuál* es la *posición* sintáctica de *Los niños* en **3a.**? No parece ser la de sujeto de *parec**e**, porque *Los niños* *no* puede concordar con él, debe concordar con *están*, y ya hemos dicho que el verdadero *sujeto* de *parec**e*** debe ser la subordinada, que *sí* concuerda con él y además es su único argumento.

Si, tras *Los niños*, fueran necesarias una coma y una entonación semi-ascendente, podríamos decir que la construcción (3a) existe para que “Los niños” pueda actuar como «Tópico», como en (3d):

- **3d.** Los niños, parec**e** [que __ están divirtiéndose mucho] (con ascenso a «Tópico»: *gramatical*)

Cabe justificar, pues, la existencia de **3d.**, además de la versión «básica» **3b**. Sin embargo, ni la coma ni la entonación semi-ascendente es necesaria en **3a.**, la cual, sin embargo, es correcta.  No parece, pues, que **3a.** sea un caso de Topicalización, y, obviamente, *Los niños* tampoco es ahí un posible *foco* (información nueva o considerada prominente); al contrario. Ya que, que yo sepa, aparte de Tópico y Foco (y sujeto, claro está), nadie ha propuesto otras posiciones estructurales que sea preciso rellenar en la periferia izquierda de la cláusula, y dado que, en español, una lengua «pro-drop», ni siquiera es necesario rellenar con algo audible la posición sintáctica de sujeto, no encuentro justificación al «ascenso» de *Los niños* en **3a**.

Por tanto, PREGUNTO:

¿Para qué existe **3a.**, aparentemente en contra del principio de «Economía», y qué posición ocupa, y qué función adicional desempeña en ella, el sujeto «desplazado» *Los niños*?

Comment: En español se pueden reordenar elementos componentes de una oración, simplemente por cuestión de énfasis. En mi opinión (3a) y (3b) son gramaticalmente idénticas y solo se diferencian en el orden enfático.

Comment: ¿Por qué piensas que la cláusula subordinada en «parece que …» es el sujeto?  Si fuese así, no sería posible, al convirtir la frase en interrogativa (*¿Parece que los niños…?*), contestar con «Sí, lo parece».  Pero obviamente, lo es.

Comment: Hablo del argumento sujeto, no de lo que ocupe la posición sintáctica de sujeto, que puede ser un comodín. Por definición, todo predicado implica un argumento sujeto. Como "parece" es inacusativo y 'ligero', su argumento sujeto se realiza como complemento y no puede ascender (Cf. "*Que están divirtiéndose parece __"), así que es un comodín (en español, uno inaudible) co-indizado con él lo que hace de sujeto sintáctico vicario. Como la sustitución por "lo" no detecta la diferencia entre un O.D., un atributo y el complemento de "parece", que sea posible no invalida el análisis precedente.

Comment: Desconozco la teorías de la nueva sintaxis que mencionas, lo único que puedo aportarte son estos dos libros:
https://books.google.es/books?id=5G8Cixl-XeIC&lpg=PP1&pg=PP1#v=onepage&q&f=false (pág. 183 en adelante)
https://books.google.es/books?id=Uy4n9MzmDJQC&lpg=PP1&pg=PP1#v=onepage&q&f=false (pág. 352 en adelante)

Comment: Por lo que he visto en el primer libro, me parece que por medio de la regla *Elevación del Sujeto como Sujeto* sobre la oración sustantiva "los niños están divirtiéndose mucho" (post-extraposicion + inserción de que) y convierte "los niños" de sujeto de la sustantiva a sujeto de la oración principal.

Comment: Ya que la oración subordinada presenta un verbo en forma personal.

Comment: Al responder a guifa olvidé decir que, en mi español, al menos, el sustituto de la cláusula no es "lo" sino "eso". Si A y B dialogan y A dice "Los niños parece etc.", por defecto B respondería "Eso parece". Sólo respondería "Lo parece" si su intención fuera decir que, aunque lo parece, a juicio de B en realidad no es así. Ello implica que la cláusula es un sujeto, sólo que, por el escaso 'peso' (en 'información') del predicado "parece", no puede 'ascender' a posición pre-verbal dejando a "parece" como Foco de la oración. Tal función de Foco 'informacional' debe desempeñarla la subordinada.

Comment: @Sibutlasi: I suggest you look for an Artificial Intelligence page, since it seems you like putting language and logic very close together. You seem to have a passion for looking at language as a purely logical system, and that goes well with people who have been trying to make computers "think as humans..." I think... Update...nevermind...I see now in your user profile that you actually ARE a professor of linguistics. "Figures" :)

Comment: @Sibutlasi - Se pueded decir también: *Así parece.*

Answer (score 3):

Primero que todo, en mi opinión la oración **3a** es simplemente un equivalente a la **3b**, con el sintagma *Los niños* en otra posición. Este sintagma no es sujeto del verbo *parece*, pues **no hay concordancia gramatical de número entre ellos**.

Veamos un análisis muy simple de la oración **3a**:

```
Los niños parece [que __ están divirtiéndose mucho] 
\_______/ \____/         \___/
 plural   singular       plural
```

Fijándose solamente en el número, vemos que *Los niños* (único sintagma nominal presente en la oración) no puede ser sujeto de la forma verbal *parece*, sino que de la forma verbal *están*.

*Los niños* no es sujeto de la oración, ni menos es un "sujeto desplazado". La oración **3a** es equivalente a la **3b**.

<sub>Con esto, espero responder tu pregunta puntual. Más tarde espero hacer un análisis más profundo de la teoría con que introduces la pregunta, la gran mayoría de esos conceptos no los manejo aún, y no recuerdo haberlos visto en los muy breves estudios de sintaxis que he hecho.</sub>

Comment: Gracias, pero su primera afirmación es una 'petición de principio': si 3a es equivalente a 3b o no, y cómo puede serlo si lo es, es precisamente de lo que se trata. La segunda es correcta, pero, si relee la pregunta, verá que eso ni remotamente se pone en cuestión. En cuanto a la tercera, "los niños", obviamente, no es el sujeto de toda la oración, pero sí es el sujeto 'desplazado' de "están". Su última afirmación insiste en la primera, y ya he dicho que se trata de probar si es o no así. Si fuera así, la 'teoría minimista' se enfrentaría a un serio problema (que se describe en la pregunta).

Answer (score 0):

Out of my own experience: The sentence seems more of a composite of two sentences, the first one calling someone's attention to the kids, and the second one giving an opinion of what is being observed.

Other than that, there is little reason to say anything like that.  It's unusual in a written context.  I'd say, don't get too technical with it.  That's not the best way to learn a language...in my "humble" opinion :)

===
Update:  Now that I read it again, it seems to imply some sort of doubt (note: My experience is as a native spaker and reader of the language).

Comment: No, syntactically speaking, such sentences are 'complex', but single sentences. The problem is that, under certain theoretical assumptions - which may well be wrong and need modification - (3a) should not exist, but it does, and, as a native speaker, I assure you it is normal in both  spoken and written Spanish. Only such theoretical assumptions make (3a) a problem. Abandon them and there is no more 'reason' to say (3b) or (1a) than there is to say (3a). Adopt them and those three different sentences must exist for some reason, why (3a) exists becomes obscure, and the question makes sense.

Comment: Now that I read it again (and I'm also a native speaker), it seems to imply some sort of doubt.  As far as the written form goes, I still don't think is common. But I'm not an "expert," just a native speaker and native reader of the language (by the way, I don't think I know what "theoretical assumptions" are being talked about).

Comment: All of (1a), (3a), (3b) and (3d) imply 'doubt', because the verb "parecer" inevitably functions as an epistemic hedge. As to the 'theoretical assumptions' I refer to as the source of the problem, they boil down to this: the principle of Economy predicts that unnecessary or, computationally speaking, unnecessarily 'costly' constructions should not exist unless something must be expressed that requires the sdditional computation, but what that extra 'semantic effect' may be in (3a) is unclear. Hence, (3a) is a problem only if Economy (= minimal computation) is a principle of Human Language.

Comment: Sorry.  I meant they imply EXTRA doubt (I use caps for emphasis, not shouting).  I've noticed that language in general isn't all that logical, since it not only expresses thoughts but also feelings.  And feelings are a messy thing.

Answer (score 0):

Since my question has been here for some time and nobody seems to have much to say about it, I suppose it is time I disclosed what my own best current guess is. Needless to say, I may be dead wrong, but this is, more or less, what I suppose is going on here:

Sentence 3a. is, indeed, just a variant of 3d., and a case of 'topicalization', but one that does **not** require the 'topic' to be detached from the main body of the clause because the latter does not have a subject in its canonical subject position, i.e., in the 'Specifier of Tense' (or whatever we call the functional head that licenses finite subject + predícate structures). Note that, in both 3a. and 3d., the subject of *parece* is the postverbal subordinate clause *que __están divirtiéndose mucho*.

Since Information Structure requires clauses to have a 'topic' (as well as a 'comment' and, inside it, a 'focus'), when no non-subject is meant to play the 'topic' role and is shifted forward into the 'Specifier of Top' position in order to asume that function, whatever lands in the canonical subject position (= Specifier of T), in most cases the real subject, is also automatically interpreted as 'topic by default’.

In other words, when a **non-subject** is meant to function as 'topic', it must be fronted/copied into the canonical ‘topic’ position (= Specifier of Top), and be detached, by comma/half-rising tone, from the rest of the ‘predication’, as happens in ‘normal’ cases of 'topicalisation' (e.g. in *De ese asunto, mi mujer no quiere hablar__, Un libro tan difícil como el de Chomsky, nuestros alumnos de Lingüística no pueden leerlo,* etc.). However, when there is no non-subject meant to asume the 'topic' role, the subject of the clause must itself be interpreted as 'topic by default', as in *Los estudiantes de lenguas modernas [= subject and topic by default] quieren que la facultad ofrezca el chino y el árabe*. That explains why many speakers nowadays **incorrectly** detach the subject of the clause from the predicate, particularly if the subject is long.

Summarising so far: in the absence of a proper 'topic' in the (orthographically and phonetically detached) Specifier of Top, whatever can reach the Specifier of Tense is interpreted as 'topic by default’.

What happens, then, if the real subject of the main clause cannot ascend into the Specifier of T because it must play an incompatible informational role, say, Focus, and remain at the end of the clause? [Observe that that is exactly the case in our ‘basic’ sentence 3b. *Parece que los niños están divirtiéndose mucho*; cf. *Que los niños están divirtiéndose mucho parece].

Of course, in such circumstances, the Specifier of T will remain available for an NP/DP to ascend into it and asume the ‘default topic’ role, **even if it cannot** thereby become the subject of the finite verb because, for both thematic and agreement-related reasons, the subject must be unique. In this case, the clause *Que los niños están divirtiéndose mucho* is, thematically speaking, a perfectly possible subject argument of the epistemic verb *parece* and agrees with it in person and number, but *Los niños* is neither thematically possible (cf. *Los niños parecen) nor agreement-wise compatible (*Los niñoS [plural] <> parecE [singular]). That explains why, even though the NP/DP *Los niños* eventually lands in the Specifier of T, it cannot thereby become the subject of *parece*.

With all that in place, we can now return to our 3d. and 3a. examples above. In 3d. the NP/DP *Los niños* has been canonically ‘topicalised’ and occupies the detached Specifier of Top position, whereas Specifier of T (i.e., the canonical pre-verbal subject position) is apparently ‘empty’ (although, depending on which version of the Chomskian 'machinery' is adopted, it may have to be occupied by a silent ‘dummy’ that forms a third-person singular ‘chain’ with the postverbal clause, or agreement between *parece* and its subject will not be accounted for; I leave that detail open). In the 3a. variant, on the contrary, the plural NP/DP subject of the subordinate clause, *Los niños*, has ascended from its own clause into the ‘empty’ Specifier of T of the main clause and thereby acquired the function of ‘default topic' of the latter (but **not** that of subject of the latter). As Specifier of T, contrary to Specifier of Top, is not ‘detached’ from the ‘predicate’ (not in the standard language, anyway), no comma/half-rising intonation is needed between it and the verb (although, as stated, speakers often incorrectly insert one).

What we see in 3a. and 3d., in sum, is two alternative 'topicalisation' strategies: a) the ‘default’ strategy, available to subjects generally (provided nothing else is meant to play the topic role) and to non-subjects (although only in the special circumstances that concur here), and b) the ‘marked’ strategy, which is generally available to non-subjects independently of whether the canonical subject position (Specifier of T) is filled by a subject argument or by a phonetically null category (a silent ‘dummy’), in the case of verbs like *parece*.

If things are as I suspect, a) there is no redundancy, because both 'topicalisation' strategies are necessary (although in different circumstances), and b) 3a. constitutes no infraction against the general principle of Economy, because raising a non-subject 'topic' into the ‘default topic’ position an **empty** Specifier of T provides is a ‘smaller’ (= computationally cheaper) displacement than raising it into the more distant Specifier of Top, but c) in that case, Specifier of T cannot contain even a 'dummy', the 'agreement' features of T must be non-locally satisfied by the clause itself), and, especially, d) **it is 3d. that should not be possible,** to the extent that 3a. achieves the same effect more economically.

In other words, the non-default topicalisation strategy should be possible only when the default one is not available because the Specifier of T is occupied by a proper argument, e.g., *todo el mundo* in a sentence like *Los niños, **todo el mundo** está de acuerdo en que __ están divirtiéndose mucho*. In 3d., on the contrary, where the Specifier of T is **not** occupied by an argument, *Los niños* should **not** ascend as far as the Specifier of Top and the sentence should sound **less** aceptable than 3a.

For what it may be worth, to me, it does, but, of course, my Spanish may well be idiosyncratic in this respect.

Thanks for your patience (and all comments welcome!)

Comment: Why did you answer to yourself???

Comment: That's one of the options available, why shouldn't I? The fact that I should have asked the question does not mean that I had absolutely no ideas about what the answer MIGHT be, only that I was not sure. Since, after several weeks, nobody here seems to have any sort of answer, giving what I suspect could be one is a perfectly legitimate way to elicit comments from others that might prove my guess incorrect and indirectly point me in the right direction, isn't it? If you have a better guess, I will be delighted to hear what it is, :-)!

Answer (score -1):

La pregunta planteada es «"¿Qué posición ocupa y qué función tiene “Los niños” en “Los niños parece que están divirtiéndose mucho”?».

En mi modesta opinión es tan simple como:

- ¿Qué posición ocupa? -> el principio de la frase
- ¿Qué función tiene? -> indicar quién se está divirtiendo mucho